# Datadog : How to show value of log attribute of a json array in monitor with log.attribute.ATTRIBUTE

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I have a json of the following format

```
{"contextKeys": [
{"name":"DataDogQues"},
{"priority":"high"}],
"comment":"Please Help!"
}
```

I am trying to fetch the value of name alone in Monitors but I am unable to do so.
log.attributes.[contextKeys.name] fetches the entires conextKeys json array.

Is there any means to fetch just the name from contextKeys in Monitors? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following path in Monitors:

```
log.attributes.contextKeys.0.name
```

> '.0': selects the first element of the array (index 0).
>
> '.name': extracts the "name" field from the selected element.

Comment: I tried the above code. It still does not work. Is there anything else I could try ?

Comment: @SherinaSundarrajan Do you use Jinja template language?